# Swift: Apple Mach-O Linker (id) Error - Xcode 8.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoapods, xcode8

I have created swift app into Xcode 8.3 and added objective-c framework into my app using cocoa pods. i have Mach-O Linker error in xcode 8.3 but its build successfully into xcode 9 works fine. i upload error screenshot below.

[image]

after that linker error i have added **libsqlite3 into Linked Frameworks and Libraries**.i have got **could not build objective-c module** error

Answer (score 0):

select your target

> general  >> Linked Frameworks and Libraries >> click on + sign >>add
>   sqlite framework >> libsqlite3.0.tbd and libsqlite3.tbd

[image]

Comment: yes i added libsqlite3 into my objective c framework